# Is there a program or system which will tell me what length (8' or 10') 1x3 lumber to get for making storm windows?

Tags: windows, carpentry, materials, measuring

I am going to make some storm windows. 13 of them. The windows will be simple 1x3 frames with a 1x3 horizontal stretcher midway up. Mitered corners. I am including the measurements at the bottom of the question.

The question is - is there software or a trick that I can use to determine if I should get 8' or 10' or a combination of the two? Of course the system should also help determine which pieces to cut out of which board to maximize the wood use, aka minimize waste?

62.5" x 31.5"

62.5" x 31.5"

62.5" x 31.5"

62.5" x 33.5"

62.5" x 26"

62.5" x 26"

62.5" x 28"

62.5" x 24"

62.5" x 24"

62.5" x 24"

63" x 26.5"

63" x 26.5"

63" x 27.25"

Comment: Unless you are spending extra money to get clear wood (a.k.a no knots or crazy grain) you will end up with some waste simply because you have to cut and fit around knots and imperfections in the boards.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I'm planning on using poplar and don't anticipate much waste due to knots.

Answer (score 2):

You will need all 8' material. The amount of waste you will have would be minimal Any of the numbers do not add up to 96". The stretchers will also work with 8" stock too, with little waste. There you will in essence be using 24" and 32 " lengths.

Cut everything to a rough length, then set up jigs to make your repeat cuts.

Comment: Ok, good enough and thanks for the sanity check.